# Import specific fields into MongoDB from exported mongo json file

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want to import an exported json file into existing collection (the same one) using `--upsert` option, but the problem is that I wanna just update specific fields not all the data. As an example I've a collection named `users`, I exported it to `users.json`, then I wanna import this `json` file into another database which has the same collection, but I want just to import fields like `email`,`username` & `avatar`, so I can keep the other data as it is without any changes. How can I do something like this? Do you've any idea or a quick hack to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi @Azzurio, have you found a nice solution ? I have the same problem.
Eric

Answer (score 1):

Here an example. The first request export a JSON file.
The second request import the file with the merge option.

```
mongoexport --db mydb --collection mycollection --fields field1,field2 --query "add a query if necessary" > test.json

mongoimport --db mydb --collection mycollection --file test.json --mode merge
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python

```
import pymongo
import json

conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
collection = conn['db']['collection']

for doc in json.load(open('users.json')):
    new_doc = {k: v for k, v in doc.iteritems() if k in ('email', 'username', 'avatar')}
    collection.update({'_id': doc['_id']}, {'$set': new_doc})
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit the fields you export is probably the more elegant approach. There is the [`--fields` flag available in `mongoexport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--fields):

```
mongoexport --fields foo, bar, baz
```

will only export `_id`, `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

Comment: So how can I merge these fields when I importing the file?